# Returning incorrect type from a function

Tags: c#, inheritance

Ok, I was scanning through some code yesterday and I saw this,

Code:

```
public class MyBaseClass
    {
        public string Field0()
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public class MyClass : MyBaseClass
    {
        public string Field1()
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Pretty simple no complaints there. In the main code,

Code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private MyBaseClass GetSomthing()
        {
            var retVal = new MyClass();
            return retVal;
        }
```

Now this code compiles correctly even though function GetSomthing() has a return type of MyBaseClass, it actually allows the return of MyClass(I assume that this is because of the inheritence).

I spotted this in somone elses code and to me it seems poor practice, although I may be missing somthing, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why is it poor practice? That's absolutely fine. For example, you might want:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetNames()
{
    return new List<string> { "Fred", "Jon", "Joe" };        
}
```

It makes perfect sense from an encapsulation point of view - you're separating the *interface* of what you're willing to guarantee to the caller (it will be a sequence of strings) from the *implementation* (you're using a `List<string>`). This lets you change the implementation later without disturbing callers.

It's *good* practice rather than *poor* practice.

Answer (score 2):

An instance of `MyClass` is also an instance of `MyBaseClass`, so it is perfectly valid (and common) to do that...